# Infinitive usage (which sentence is correct)

Tags: infinitives, lyrics

I am working on the lyrics for one of my songs and english is not my first language.
Here's the question - which of these sentences is correct?

1. No thorns to prick your heart
2. No thorns to prick your heart with

(Meaning that the character of the song has no 'thorns' (figuratively) he/she could use to prick the heart of the one he/she addresses to)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with the infinitive?

Comment: It sounds like you're actually asking about preposition usage.

Comment: The 'with' here strongly connotes intentional use of an instrument (eg _one of those things for getting stones out of horses' hooves with_).

Comment: This has to do with the infinitive because thses are relative infinitives, which modify and refer to the nouns they follow. This coreference can be either with the **subject** of the infinitive, as in _No thorns to prick your heart_, where _thorns_ is the subject of _prick_; or it can be with the **object** of the infinitive, as in _No heart for thorns to prick_; or  it can be with the **object of a preposition**, as in _No thorns to prick your heart with_. All these are normal, common, conversational English constructions.

Answer (score 2):

If they're song lyrics, you can choose either one and claim [*artistic license*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license) for lacking proper grammar. The most important part of lyrics is that they flow well with the music.

> Artistic license (also known as dramatic license, historical license, poetic license, narrative license, licentia poetica, or simply license) is a colloquial term, sometimes euphemism, used to denote the distortion of fact, alteration of the conventions of grammar or language, or rewording of pre-existing text made by an artist in the name of art.
>
> <sup>*(source: Wikipedia)*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As Ian MacDonald has said, poets and song-writers will make free with niceties of grammar and be excused.

It seems clear to me that

> No thorns to prick your heart

is by far the nicer phrase; that "with" on the end feels plodding. I might well use **with** earlier in the line:

> And there wistful she stands with no thorns to prick your heart

but we find the English speakers elide such words. A song-writing tutor of mine spoke of vacuuming up the inessentials.

> And there wistful she stands, no thorns to prick your heart